# How can we determine the relationship between A and C if A is greater than B and B is not equal to C?

Tags: inequality

Given $A, B , C >0$.
If $A > B \ne C$, what can we say about $A$ and $C$. Is $A$ greater than $C$ or smaller than $C$?

Comment: You can't say anything about them.

Comment: A dog heavier than a fly, a fly and an elephant have different weights, a fly and a mosquito also have different weights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can say given information is not sufficient. So relation between A and C can't be established.

Answer (score 1):

For a simple example, let $A=4,B=3$.  Then $C=1$ and $C=5$ are both possibilities.  The fact that $B \neq C$ is not very restrictive.

Comment: Indeed, and furthermore $C=4$ is *also* permissible. So $A<C, A=C, A>C$ are all possible when given $A>B$ and $B\neq C$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $B=1$.   Then we know $A>1$ and $C\neq 1$ but we do how they may compare to each other.   There is no comparison implied by that condition.

Examples $\{A=3, C=2\}$ satisfies the condition, though so does $\{A=3, C=3\}$, and also $\{A=3,C=4\}$.

This remains so for any value of $B$. Thus $A>B$ and $B\neq C$ permits any of $A<C, A=C, A>C$.